# Trouble with types when passing vector to function in c++

Tags: c++, vector

I am starting a c++ class having never done anything in the language before, and I'm pretty confused by vectors.I made a toy example and I don't quite understand why the doubles that I put into a vector become vector's. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<double> a;
void func(vector<double> *);

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        a.push_back(double(i));
    }   
    func(&a);
    return 0;
}   

void func(vector<double> *vec)
{
    cout << double(vec[0]) << endl;
    return; 
}
```

It ends up giving me this error:
error: cannot convert 'vector' to 'double' without
      a conversion operator
and I have no idea what that means. What exactly is happening here and how can I cast a vector into a double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mix using pointers `*` with `std::vector`.

### Method 1 (not recommended):

Change

```
cout << double(vec[0]) << endl;
```

to

```
cout << double((*vec).at(0)) << endl;
```

### Method 2:

1. Change

   ```
   void func(vector<double> *vec)
   ```

   to

   ```
   void func(vector<double> vec)
   ```

   or

   ```
   void func(const vector<double> &vec)
   ```
2. Change

   ```
   func(&a);
   ```

   to

   ```
   func(a);
   ```

Comment: Oh sweet, that works perfect, but why does that work? Am I wrong to think about vectors as just arrays that can be resized easily?

Comment: @user1023465 It's a bad practice to mix using pointers `*` with `std::vector`.

Comment: Could you explain that a little bit more? It seems like arrays and pointers work so well together, and vectors are so similar to arrays...

Comment: Passing a vec on the stack is a pretty bad idea. `vector<double> vec` should be `const vector<double>& vec`

Comment: @user1023465 "Am I wrong to think about vectors as just arrays that can be resized easily?" -- Yes, completely wrong. A vector is an object instance.

Comment: @user1023465 Add another method to work it out. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Okay yeah I have seen it written like that in my textbook. Thanks a lot for all you guys' help!

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the actual error is more due to a misunderstanding of pointers than vectors . The problem is that you are passing a pointer to a vector. If you want to use the vector itself, then you would do:

```
cout << (*vec)[0] << endl;
```

`*` will dereference the pointer to get the actual vector instance rather than an index into an address which is what you were doing before.

But, as pointed out in the other answer, it is safer just to pass the vector by reference (or better yet, const reference):

```
void func(const vector<double>& vec)
{
    cout << vec[0] << endl;
    return; 
}
```

then call as:

```
func(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to use `vectors` is with a `std::vector< TYPE >::const_iterator` like this;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

double func(std::vector<double>::const_iterator iter);


int main()
{
    std::vector<double> vec;

    for (double i = 0.0; i < 1; i += 0.1){
        vec.push_back(i);
    }

    std::cout<< func(vec.begin()+3) << " "

             << func(vec.begin()+6) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}  

double func(std::vector<double>::const_iterator iter){
    return *iter;
}
```

outputs;

```
0.3 0.6
```